# Adding a $ in excel formula?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically while recording an macro in excel...

I am trying to lock a value in a cell ...

this is the formula:

```
=Menu!$M$11-I3-J3
```

but in vba it doesnt shows the $ symbol in it..

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=Menu!R[8]C[9]-RC[5]-RC[6]"
```

Hope someone is able to help me out~

Comment: Absolute references and relative are indicated by the presence or absence of [] with R1C1 reference notation as shown above.

Comment: What cell is the formula in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for [R1C1-style reference](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm) you have presence or absence of [] indicating absolute v relative

e.g.  R[#] relative, or R# for absolute

i.e. Absolute References do not include square brackets around the numbers.

Comment: But in the OP's formula, both the relative and the absolute came out with brackets.  Would you please clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect they didn't enter as shown. They should use the macro recorder when inserting the formula =Menu!$M$11-I3-J3  into a cell and then inspect the recorded code.